# Demonstration of a problem using combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I got an assigment for homework and haven't got a clue about how to solve it, it goes as follows:

"Given a set of 12 integers, demonsrate that the subtraction of 2 integers of said set is divisible by 11"

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this seems to mean is that in any set of twelve integers, there is at least one pair whose difference is divisible by 11.

Hint: use the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) when looking at the remainders when each of your twelve integers are divided by 11.

Comment: I do understand the pigeonhole principle, but I'm not sure about applying it to infinite sets, could you please be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: @Darkkurama: Try to choose 12 integers and look at their remainders when dividing by 11. See if any match. Then try another 12 integers. Then think about the pigeonhole principle again.

Comment: @Darkkurama: The set of integers we are looking at has 12 elements. What infinite set do you mean?

Comment: Well the set is not infinite but its numbers can be any integer .